# How to make a whole column have the same text in google sheets

Tags: google-slides

I want to have all of the cells in the "subject" column to have the same text as the second cell down. I want to be able to just edit that cell and have all the other cells edited as well without copying and pasting. this is to do mass emails for my business so formatting is essential. screenshot example below. [screenshot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5YQA.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own. you type in the cell that you want the text copied into with the coordinates of the one you are copying eg. "=D2" In this case, I used $ symbols so that when I copied it all the way down it would keep the current coordinate. the function ended up being "=$D$2" all the way down the column.